# CSS: How to move text link to the right inside li

Tags: css, html-lists, positioning, text-align

I want to move slightly to the right a text link that is aligned to the left inside a li.

Which is something similar to left:2px; but only applied to the text.

**Page link:** http://npmaudiovisual.com/esde/?page_id=36

[image]

**CSS:**

```
#secondnav li a {
    border: medium none;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 8px;
}
#secondnav li a {
    display: block !important;
    line-height: 42px !important;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 230px;
}
#secondnav li a {
    background-color: #FFC477;
    border: 1px solid white !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px !important;
    position: relative;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `text-indent` alone or `padding-left` and reduce `width` by the same amount.

Answer (score 0):

Change the padding to something like "3px 0px 3px 18px". the order is: "top right bottom left".

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your css

```
#secondnav li a {
    text-indent: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the a{ element a margin-left of the px you want. For example:

`   #secondnav li a {
         margin-left: 3px;
    }

`